# Sum of the values of certain rows into a new column using R

Tags: r

I'm currently using data that has four columns that i want to sum by their unique ID into a new column. I'm new to using R so any help is appreciated! thank you

Example of the input columns and desired output:

[image: Here]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make a good question, please provide some reproducible data and some code showing what you have managed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (using the iris dataset as an example)

```
iris$new_col <- iris$Sepal.Length + iris$Sepal.Width
```

For your example

```
df$Sum <- df$Pillar_1 + df$Pillar_2 + df$Pillar_3
```

This supposes your dataframe is called `df`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  opportunity = c(
    639495, 303678, 629464, 297662, 302891
  ),
  `Pillar 1` = c(
    4, 3, 5, 3, 2
  ),
  `Pillar 2` = c(
    7, 8, 9, 4, 4
  ),
  `Pillar 3` = c(
    4, 6, 2, 5, 8
  )
)

df %>% mutate(
  Sum = `Pillar 1` + `Pillar 2` + `Pillar 3`
)
```

Yielding the output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  opportunity `Pillar 1` `Pillar 2` `Pillar 3`   Sum
                           
1      639495          4          7          4    15
2      303678          3          8          6    17
3      629464          5          9          2    16
4      297662          3          4          5    12
5      302891          2          4          8    14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
  opportunity = c(
    639495, 303678, 629464, 297662, 302891
  ),
  Pillar1 = c(
    4, 3, 5, 3, 2
  ),
  Pillar2 = c(
    7, 8, 9, 4, 4
  ),
  Pillar3 = c(
    4, 6, 2, 5, 8
  )
)

df$Sum <- apply(df[,-1], 1, sum)
```

---

```
> df
  opportunity Pillar1 Pillar2 Pillar3 Sum
1      639495       4       7       4  15
2      303678       3       8       6  17
3      629464       5       9       2  16
4      297662       3       4       5  12
5      302891       2       4       8  14
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, you could also do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(select(., contains("Pillar"))))
```

Output:

```
  opportunity Pillar1 Pillar2 Pillar3 Sum
1      639495       4       7       4  15
2      303678       3       8       6  17
3      629464       5       9       2  16
4      297662       3       4       5  12
5      302891       2       4       8  14
```

If you'd want to include in the `Sum` certain columns which do not contain `Pillar` as a string, you can also filter by index like:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(select(., 2:4)))
```

Or instead of `2:4` just `-1` if you want to sum all columns except first one (as already indicated in one of the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(Sum = select(., starts_with('Pillar')) %>%
                 reduce(`+`))
#   opportunity Pillar1 Pillar2 Pillar3 Sum
#1      639495       4       7       4  15
#2      303678       3       8       6  17
#3      629464       5       9       2  16
#4      297662       3       4       5  12
#5      302891       2       4       8  14
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(opportunity = c(639495, 303678, 629464, 297662, 
 302891), Pillar1 = c(4, 3, 5, 3, 2), Pillar2 = c(7, 8, 9, 4, 
 4), Pillar3 = c(4, 6, 2, 5, 8)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```